# how to do custom validation for redux-form field on button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

is there any way to set the field validation as true or false in a button click? or any way to pass customized validation to that field only on button action and on blur?

I want to do custom filed validation on button click. I need to validate the entered value with some API call. I will utilize this new validation in field blur and in button click.

I am unable to find a clue to achieve this. could some please suggest me on this.

```
<Field name={`${name}.complete`}
              label="Australian postal address"
              placeholder={this.props.placeholder} 
              component={NewTextInput}
              onChange={this.triggerAutoSuggest.bind(this)}
              onkeypressfun={this.triggerKeyevent.bind(this)}
              showspinner={this.state.showspinner}
              onBlur={this.validateAddressfun.bind(this)}
              ref="autocompletefiled"
              autoComplete="nope"
              type="text"
              validate={[requiredGeneric]}
            />

<button onClick={this.validateField}>validate Filed value</button>
```

If you can suggest some work around also will fine to me.

Comment: In `redux-form` validation is done by passing config properties on the `renderForm` method. You have `validate`, `asyncValidate` and `asyncBlurFields`. I suggest to take a look at the docs and use that approach

Comment: yeah I tried in different ways. I want to call that new validation rule only on blur or button click. i don't want to call in change. 
is there any way to  do setvalidate("fieldname",false)?